# pyparsing - 2nd execution of the same statement throws an exception

Tags: python, pyparsing

Could you explain why the second execution of exactly the same `parseString` throws the `pyparsing.ParseException: not a subentry` exception, please?

Code:

```
from pyparsing import *
from pprint import pprint

indentStack = [1]
stmt = Forward()
suite = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)

funcDecl = "def" + Word(printables)
funcDef = Group( funcDecl + suite )

stmt << ( funcDef | "open" | "close")
module_body = OneOrMore(stmt)

code="""\
def process
    open
    close"""

# first execution - works fine, but modifies funcDef
pprint(funcDef)
f1 = funcDef.parseString(code)
pprint(f1)

# second execution
pprint(funcDef)
f2 = funcDef.parseString(code)  ### throws pyparsing.ParseException: not a subentry (at char 16), (line:2, col:5)
pprint(f2)


pyparsing.ParseException: not a subentry (at char 16), (line:2, col:5)
```

I tried to simplify the the example available in the pyparsing wiki:
http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/indentedGrammarExample.py

Full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/QXF5ZJZ7

Link to the documentation of `parseString`: https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#parseString

## EDIT 2018-02-20

I extended the code by `pprint(funcDef)` and I found out that after the first execution of
`funcDef.parseString(code)` the definition of `funcDef` has changed from:

from:

```
Group:({{"def" W:(0123...)} indented block})
```

to:

```
Group:({"def" W:(0123...) indented block})
```

## EDIT 2018-02-21

Adding `indentStack.pop()` before the 2nd execution of `funcDef.parseString(code)` solved the problem.

It's worth to mention that it's `indentStack = [1]` does not solve the problem. It's very interesting case so I created two snippets to show the difference (I also added few extra debug print's into the library):

- Resetting indentStack with: `indentStack = [1]`: https://pastebin.com/adPiuE8C
- Resetting indentStack with: `indentStack.pop()`: https://pastebin.com/dzWkdjni

Comment: I have just realized that the second execution of `parseTree = module_body.parseString(data)` in the pyparsing example differs to the first one.

Comment: The real issue is that `indentedBlock` uses the `indentStack` list to keep state of what the current column is. After running the parser once, `indentStack` contains `[1, 5]`. If you add another line to your sample that goes back to column 1, or explicitly reset `indentStack` back to [1] your second `parseString` call will succeed.

Comment: @gbajson... post your edits and solution (complete working code; not just the one scentence in solution itself) as self-answer instead of inside your question. You show working to an answer that way better. Otherwise the question keeps recycled in the "unasnwered-list of questions". You can select your own answer in a few days as best answer.

Comment: Ah, correct, you have to change the actual list, not just assign a new list to the name. In case your stack is multiple levels deep, do `del indentStack[1:]` or `indentStack[:] = [1]`, both of which will reset `indentStack` in place, rather than assign a new stack, which you found would not work. Make this a self-answer and you will be at peace with the Python SO.

Comment: .. just for clarity... you can post your answer now but the self-select best-answer option will be unlock in a day or two or so... ;-)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case stack is multiple levels deep.

Adding `indentStack[:] = [1]` before the 2nd execution of `funcDef.parseString(code)` solved the problem.